# Geocode not working with php on my new host

Tags: php, geocode

I had google geocoding script in PHP working on my previous host (still working), but stopped working on my VPS in hostgator.

```
$url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=?Toronto,+ON&sensor=true";
$latlon = @file_get_contents($url);
$latlong =json_decode($latlon, true);
```

I also tried:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$latlong = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Both gives

```
{
  "status": "REQUEST_DENIED",
  "results": [ ]
}
```

I tried Yahoo API and it works! (but `@file_get_contents` does not work for yahoo either).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: its nothing to do with sensor param since, i tried the same url through browser and it returns results!

Comment: Does the same code work from your local machine then? Or from another web host?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you daily limit to call webservice allowed by google is expired.